# Freeradius authenticate windows ad username and password failed while testing thru wifi setup

Tags: authentication, ntlm, freeradius

Trying to authenticate windows AD username and password by freeradius thru NTLM auth.

while testing ntlm auth in freeradius machine, got success message.

```
ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --domain=MPLradius --username=Administrator -- 
 password=abc@123456789
 NT_STATUS_OK: Success (0x0)


 While trying thru wifi , got below error

 [chap] login attempt by "sophosadmin@mplradius.local" with CHAP password
 [chap] Cleartext-Password is required for authentication
    ++[chap] = invalid
    +} # group CHAP = invalid
    Failed to authenticate the user.
    expand: BLACK -> BLACK
    Login incorrect (rlm_chap: Clear text password not available): 
    [sophosadmin@mplradius.local/<CHAP-Password>] (from client x.x.x.x port 2149580837 
    cli xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) BLACK
    Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
```

Could you help me sort out this error.